# What's the point of using an anonymous function for a one-liner?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Quite often I see code like this <s>(it's not a D3 specific thing, this is just an example)</s>:

```
svg.append("text")
    .text(function() {
        return round2DP(d.frequency); // d refers to a data element; d.frequency is a float. round2DP() rounds to 2 decimal places.
    }) // etc
```

Why use an anonymous function? Why not just write `.text(round2DP(d.frequency))`? It seems a lot simpler, more readable, and makes more sense to me: why create an unnecessary function where you don't need one? And yet I see this all the time. What is the reasoning behind things like these?

**EDIT**: To clarify, in this particular case `.text()` can accept both a function and a value, so it is not necessarily expecting a callback.

Comment: Does `.text()` accept a value directly, or does it expect a callback...?

Comment: @deceze Sorry, I've clarified it in an edit: it can take a value *or* a callback as a parameter.

Comment: If passing a callback, is that called sometime later as needed, or invoked directly anyway...? Basically: is there *any* difference at all in how `text()` treats a value and a callback? If so, that difference will probably be your answer.

Comment: @deceze As far as I know, there isn't one, but I'd be interested to find out. Maybe this question **is** D3 specific...

Comment: Are you sure it's not `.text(function(d) {` ?

Comment: @Kaiido I am. This block of code is already inside a `function(d) {` block, hence the `d` parameter that is often used this way in D3.

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#text) is the `.text()` we're talking about, then it indeed seems to make no difference at all.

Comment: And it's not chained to a `data()` function anywhere?

Comment: @Kaiido Not this block. Its parent block is, but that's not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

> Why not just write .text(round2DP(d.frequency))?

Since `function(){}` is a **function reference** and `round2DP(d.frequency)` is a **function call**.

In first case, you are passing an argument which is a funciton (not executed yet), and in second case you passing the returned value of function call.

It depends on what parameter the `text` method expects. If your `text()` method accepts a **function-reference** parameter, then you need to choose first one, else if it is looking for a returned value of `round2DP(d.frequency)` then choose second one.

If `text` accepts both and both give same output, then `which one to choose` will depend on your context. You can choose between them based on your preference of readability and maintainability.

Comment: See my edit: in this case, `.text()` can take a value as well.

Comment: @Bluefire Using call back function depends on certain context. Suppose if you want to manipulate the existing text and set it back. Then that would be the best context to use call back function. But in your case, the value is going to be same for all elements. So there is no need to use a callBack here.

Comment: @Bluefire I have explained the difference. `which is one better?` depends on your context and is off-topic (try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Because you call function instead of pass it as callback. In your case correct way will be:

```
svg.append("text")
    .text(round2DP.bind(null/*context*/, d.frequency))
```